Can I temporarily power a 200A subpanel from a 100A feeder breaker?
Long story but I currently have a 200amp through-panel outside my temporary dwelling (lets call it the cabin) which feeds a 200amp panel inside the cabin (all of our circuits feed from the 200amp inside the cabin). Using the cabin while our home is built.
Our new home is now built, and I need to switch the through-panel lugs to feed the new home instead of the cabin but i want to power the cabin a little while longer. I'd like to subpanel the cabin via a breaker in the through-panel (instead of using the lower lugs like i have been).
The service is 200amp. The through-panel is 200amp. The cabin's panel is 200amp.
So, can I run a 100amp breaker from the through panel to the 200amp main breaker in the cabin? Or is it illegal/dangerous to run a 100amp breaker to a 200amp subpanel?
Thanks

Or this? Can a sub-panel have a larger main breaker than the feeder breaker in the main panel?

That is perfectly fine.  The opposite is dangerous. Like a 200 amp breaker feeding a 100 amp panel.
Later on if you want to keep it is where load calculations come in handy, since you might leave the house with only a 100 amps to use, but you can also change to an even smaller feed breaker.
